# X99 chipset and triple channel memory configurations

Tags: memory, cpu, chipset

I'm building a system with an x99 board and a xeon e5-v3.

I'd like to know if the chipset and the processor will support a triple channel memory configuration (e.g. three or six sticks) without performance penalties. That is, achieving memory speed in between dual and quad channel configs (and NOT like a single channel config).

Quite surprisingly, it is hard to find reliable information about such matter over the Internet.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you consult the owners manual for your specific motherboard? It really does not matter what the chipset supports but what Intel bios will allow.

Comment: Yes, but it says absolutely nothing. It is an Asus X99/ws-IPMI. Note however that the Z-series supports dual channel independently from the mainboard bios.